# Mount a content database with site collection already exist in the farm

Tags: powershell, sql-server

We are using SP2013 standard on-premise. There are 2 farms **Test1** and **Test2**. Both farm have exactly same named Content DBs and same URL site collections.

Recently we encounter some issue about SharePoint patch on Test2 site collection "**/sites/ABC**". This content DB is **wss_content_abc** and this DB only contains 1 site collection. In order to troubleshoot it, we backup **wss_content_abc** from **Test2** and restore to **Test1** as **wss_content_abc_corrupt**.

(At this moment, Test1 farm have 2 content DB, **wss_content_abc** and **wss_content_abc_corrupt**)

Then on farm Test1 I run "`Dismount-SPContentDatabase wss_content_abc`" (it is the healthy database on Test1). And then following:

```
Mount-SPContentDatabase wss_content_abc_corrupt -WebApplication http://test1farm.com
Upgrade-SPContentDatabase wss_content_abc_corrupt -WebApplication http://test1farm.com
```

The upgrade works good and the site **http://test1farm.com/sites/ABC** is up.

Now I want to mount the existing healthy Content DB **wss_content_abc** back to **Test1** farm as another site collection (maybe call /sites/ABC2/) so that I can compare. How can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're the same Site Collection, that is, have the same Site Collection ID, you cannot mount it to the same farm. Instead, you need to run Backup-SPSite and Restore-SPSite (good up until ~20GB in SC size) which will generate a new Site Collection ID, and also allow you to restore it at a different path.

Comment: Can I do backup/restore towards an unmounted DB?

Comment: Not in a way that changes the ID. What you'll probably want to do is back up the current site collection at /sites/abc with Backup-SPSite, detach the CDB, re-mount the other db, then use Restore-SPSite to restore the SC backup from the test environment on a different URL.